# Was ist jedermanns/eure Lieblingssendung or Was sind eure Lieblingssendungen?

Tags: grammatical-number, indefinite-pronoun

I do not want to ask about a tv-show that is liked by all, instead I want to ask a group that each of its members tell me his personal favorite tv-show.

Would I use jedermann or eure, and if so, would I ask about plural **Sendungen** or about **Sendung**?

> a) Was ist jedermanns Lieblingssendung?
> b) Was ist eure Lieblingssendung?
> c) Was sind jedermanns Lieblingssendungen? (1 per person)
> d) Was sind eure Lieblingssendungen? (still asking about 1 per person)

Or do I need to be more clear in order to avoid misunderstandings? My attempt:

> Welche eine Fernsehsendung mag jeder einzelne von euch persönlich?

Answer (score 2):

Only variant d)

> Was sind eure Lieblingssendungen?

would be understood as you intend.

Variants a) and b), by the use of singular, would ask for a single favorite show shared by all.

Variants a) and c), by the use of "jedermann", lack the limitation to those present, effectively asking about the favorite show(s) of everybody in the world.

Comment: The limitation to those present can be implicit in a) and c); these sentences are ambiguous. I also don't agree that a) and b) necessarily ask for a single show shared by all; the genitive *jedermanns* allows a distributive reading. Since *jedermanns* is kind of limited, natural examples are hard to come by, but I like the following: *Wenn ich zuhöre, hänge ich an jedermanns Lippen — egal was er sagt und wer er ist* (via [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r)).